# How and where to setup TelemetryClient within a netcore webApp?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I am looking to use the TrackTrace method associated with Telemetry client. An instance of TelemetryClient needs to be created in order to access this method.

A TelemetryClient can be initialised in the constructor of a controller but I was looking to see if there is a better approach and how it would be implemented?

Comment: Better approach in the sense?

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#frequently-asked-questions):

> Get an instance of TelemetryClient by using constructor injection, and call the required TrackXXX() method on it. We don't recommend creating new TelemetryClient instances in an ASP.NET Core application.
>
> A singleton instance of TelemetryClient is already registered in the
> DependencyInjection container, which shares TelemetryConfiguration
> with rest of the telemetry. Creating a new TelemetryClient instance is
> recommended only if it needs a configuration that's separate from the
> rest of the telemetry.

So you can just get it injected wherever you need like this:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private TelemetryClient telemetry;

    // Use constructor injection to get a TelemetryClient instance.
    public HomeController(TelemetryClient telemetry)
    {
        this.telemetry = telemetry;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Call the required TrackXXX method.
        this.telemetry.TrackEvent("HomePageRequested");
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I was looking to see if there is a better approach and how it would be implemented?

To create a instance of TelemetryClient, you could just use the new operator.

```
TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
```

Before using the TelemetryClient, you need to configure the Application Insight from Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: Any update? If you have further questions related to this topic, please feel free to let me know.